# How to enable logging done by netty code?

Tags: http, logging, netty

I have written an HTTP server using netty framework. I have done logging for the HTTP server ().
I also want to enable the logging done inside the netty code.What steps do I need to follow to print the log statements of the netty code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure the InternalLoggerFactory of needed and set the right delegation. By default it will first try to use slf4j, log4j and then JUL.